# Why capistrano 3 linked files aways fails on dry run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano, capistrano3

When I run `bundle exec cap production deploy:check:linked_files` I got success but if I add --dry-run to test, it aways fails.

See the Outputs:

`bundle exec cap production deploy:check:linked_files`

```
DEBUG [c593caa5] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/database.yml ] as app@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [c593caa5] Command: [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [c593caa5] Finished in 3.206 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [9619277e] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/mongoid.yml ] as app@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [9619277e] Command: [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/mongoid.yml ]
DEBUG [9619277e] Finished in 0.304 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And with --dry-run:

`bundle exec cap production deploy:check:linked_files --dry-run`

```
DEBUG [26483ac3] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/database.yml ] as app@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [26483ac3] Command: [ -f /home/app/www/shared/config/database.yml ]
ERROR linked file /home/app/www/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This is expected or its some kind of bug?

Comment: Probably not expected as I can't reproduce your situation. If I run those two commands on a program of my own, both come back successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug due to how `--dry-run` works in Capistrano. During a dry run, all `test` commands return `false`. So Capistrano thinks the linked files do not exist, and it gives up.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1565